# Does a EU student in the UK automatically get a National Insurance Number (NIN, NINO)?

Tags: united-kingdom, eu-citizens, insurance

I lived in the UK for a full year while doing my Master's degree, six years ago. I was registered at the NHS, and I do have the number written down.

Since I was registered at the NHS, is there a chance that I was also issued a National Insurance Number? If yes, what's the easiest way to find that out? If not, what's the process?

I'm a EU national, and do have a NIN in my home country.

Comment: Were you working at any point whilst as a student in the UK?

Comment: No, I wasn't. Turns out I don't have one, better answer my own question now.

Answer (score 2):

According to the people at the National Insurance Applications call centre, a NHS number does not mean a NI number at all. So if you are registered for the NHS as a student but you've never worked in the UK, you do not have a National Insurance number. In which case you apply for one.